# Работа с view controller в xcode 6

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Понимаю, что вопрос найглупейший, но всё же он есть, и мне не найти ответ.

Собственно, есть view controller главной страницы с кнопочкой, при нажатии на которую чел переходит на второй view controller. Но вот где мне найти код как первого, так и второго view, например, для того чтобы вставить туда код парсера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если создаете с помощью сториборда, то план действий таков:

1. Первым идет навигейшнкнтроллер, потом он соединен с первым вьюконтроллером, первый вьюконтроллер соединен (через пуш) со вторым вьюконтроллером.
2. Создаем два класса наследованных от UIViewController.
3. В сториборде выделяем первый вьюконтроллер и первую вкладку (точно не помню), там прописываем имя класса первого контроллера. Также и со вторым, только там имя второго класса. При передаче данных там есть метод типа "сегвея". В нем создаем экземпляр второго контроллера, и там же передаем ему данные, если переменные не инкапсилируемые. Как-то так.

Сам создаю все программно, переходы держу в голове или на бумаге рисую наборчик контроллеров. Мозги работают лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Советую посмотреть любую серию уроков по iOS и xCode. Сейчас их очень много.